# N user should not get same data at same time for data entry person [postgres]

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want some logic that can lock data for a user. If user A select data from table then user B or C... Should not be able to select the same data from the table.
Ex: we can take an example for data entry.
If user A fire query to select data from the table and get data. At that same moment user B try to select data then He/She should get the same data in their UI.

So if there are N user who is doing data entry then No one should get some data in their UI to add/update.

We can lock data when user A selects. And can unlock once they update or if user does not update for some time. So I want some solutions similar to this or some other. I am using the Postgres database.

Comment: I am working on Postgres 11 and greater than that.

Answer (score 0):

If your transactions are short, use

```
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

Then nobody gets data that some other transaction is working on, and you never block.

If the operation takes long, add columns `locked_by` and `locked_at` (`timestamptz`) and select with

```
UPDATE ...
SET locked_by = me(), locked_at = current_timestamp
WHERE ...
  AND (coalesce(locked_by, me()) = me()
       OR locked_at < current_timestamp - expiry_time())
RETURNING *;
```

Here `me()` is an imaginary function that returns my user, and `expiry_time()` returns the time after which the lock expires.

Comment: In my case I have APIs. So if one API being called and get data. Then when other user calls API to get data then they should not get the same data. So in this case is your first solution will work?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by API in that case. But you know the SQL now, so you could design your API around that.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. @laurenz